# Is it possible to get the old workspaceswitcher back in the top-panel?

Tags: panel, workspaces

I just updated my Ubuntu from 10.04 to 12.04 yesterday and so far I'm very satisfied with it.

There is only one thing which is still missing to get back just the same comfort as I had with the previous version.

I work on 4 workspaces and would like to have the ability to switch from one to another by just one click.

With Gnome there was the possibility to add the workspace switcher to the top-panel next to the system tray and I could easily click on just the workspace I wanted to switch to.

Of course there I could switch by using the keyboard shortcuts, but I would like to use the mouse in addition. I don't like using the switcher on the left side because it's much slower.

Is it possible to get the old workplace switcher back in the panel at the top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not the exact same panel app, but a similar one seems to be working fine with Unity. It's called indicator-workspaces and there's a PPA for it

https://launchpad.net/~geod/+archive/ppa-geod

If you need help with ppa please refer to this guide that shows how to configure them

https://launchpad.net/+help-soyuz/ppa-sources-list.html

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response.
It seems as if there is no current version for Ubuntu 12.04 :/
At least I couldn't install it after adding the repository.

Comment: You're right...have you tried downloading the .deb manually and installing it? https://launchpad.net/~geod/+archive/ppa-geod/+files/indicator-workspaces_0.6.4_all.deb

Comment: Yep I trief, but the only thing I got was an error message. But thanks to your hint I found the solution here:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1971884

Well, that's not exactly the same thing as I intended to get, but at least it's better than nothing.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry but i do not know a solution for Unity. However, you can start your session with GNOME classic and everything will be more similar to the old GNOME.

In order to set up panels as in the older one, you will have to press Alt and Super keys at the same time that you use the mouse with right button to access options or middle button to arrange icons...